# keep both merging keys after pandas.merge_asof

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have found this nice function  `pandas.merge_asof`.
From the documentation

```
pandas.merge_asof(left, right, on=None, left_on=None, right_on=None)

Parameters: 

left : DataFrame
right : DataFrame
on : label

Field name to join on. Must be found in both DataFrames.
The data MUST be ordered. 
Furthermore this must be a numeric column,such as datetimelike, integer, or float. 
On or left_on/right_on must be given.
```

and it works as expected.

However, my merged dataframe keeps as columns `on` only the one that originally was in `left`. I would need to keep them both, so to have

```
   mydf=pandas.merge_asof(left, right, on='Time')
```

and `mydf` to contain both `Time` from `left` and `right`

Example data:

```
a=pd.DataFrame(data=pd.date_range('20100201', periods=100, freq='6h3min'),columns=['Time'])
b=pd.DataFrame(data=
                  pd.date_range('20100201', periods=24, freq='1h'),columns=['Time'])
b['val']=range(b.shape[0])
out=pd.merge_asof(a,b,on='Time',direction='forward',tolerance=pd.Timedelta('30min'))
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: I am on it...wait

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think one possible solution is rename columns:

```
out = pd.merge_asof(a.rename(columns={'Time':'Time1'}), 
                    b.rename(columns={'Time':'Time2'}), 
                    left_on='Time1',
                    right_on='Time2',
                    direction='forward',
                    tolerance=pd.Timedelta('30min'))

print (out.head())
                Time1      Time2  val
0 2010-02-01 00:00:00 2010-02-01  0.0
1 2010-02-01 06:03:00        NaT  NaN
2 2010-02-01 12:06:00        NaT  NaN
3 2010-02-01 18:09:00        NaT  NaN
4 2010-02-02 00:12:00        NaT  NaN
```

Comment: such a pity that still no better way than to rename

Answer (score 2):

One trick that I found while working on time-series data is this function.
To articulate what I have done is perform an outer join on both dataframes. Suppose the entry against some "Date and Time" is not in the other dataframe. In that case, we copied the value it had previously, as I assumed that the value in the other dataframe stayed whatever it was before that time.

```
def merger(df1,df2):
    
    df1['Date and Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date and Time'], errors='coerce')
    df2['Date and Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date and Time'], errors='coerce') 
   

    df = pd.merge(df1,df2,on = 'Date and Time', how='outer')
    df.fillna(method = 'ffill',inplace = True)
    
    return df
```

Hope it Helps.